# What does this php code mean?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category, menu, magento-community

Can anyone explain me what does the below coding mean?

```
$html = array();
$combineClasses = array();

    $combineClasses[] = 'level' . $level;
    if ($this->_isCurrentCategory($category)) {
        $combineClasses[] = 'active';
    } else {
        $combineClasses[] = $this->isCategoryActive($category) ? 'parent' : 'inactive';
    }
    $levelClass[] = implode('-', $combineClasses);

    if ($category->hasChildren()) {
        $levelClass[] = 'has-children';
    }

    $levelClass = array_merge($levelClass, $combineClasses);

    $levelClass[] = $this->_getClassNameFromCategoryName($category);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code generates the CSS classes to be added to the category items in the top menu.

A pseudo code could be:

- add a `level` class
- if it is the current category add an `active` class
- else add a `parent` class if it is a parent category of the current category or an `inactive` if not
- add a `has-children` class if the category has childrne
- I suppose it adds classes base on the category name

Comment: what does this` $combineClasses[] = 'level' . $level;`   mean ?  What does the `.` do? kindly explain.

Comment: @Ramya the dot is the concatenation operator of PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php